# How does my calculator calculate the roots for a cubic polynomial?

Tags: calculus, roots, quadratics, cubics, calculator

For example, many calculators come equipped with the **quadratic formula**, and so you can give them $A,B,C$ coefficients, and they will show you out the solution using the formula 
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

My calculator however finds $x$ when we have $x^3$ too, and this time it asks for $A,B,C,D$.

I was wondering how exactly it did this? Is there a cubic power "formula"? My calculator even calculates irrational roots so I'm not sure how exactly it can do this without a formula.

Comment: There is a formula. It's called Cardano's formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: I think it rather uses methodes from Numerical Analysis.

Comment: Something like Newton-Raphson

Comment: @Fightclub1995 newton takes a few iterations, so I don't think so

Comment: @KSplitX then some other method. You think it uses the formula of Cardano?

Comment: We have never seen your calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are formulas for the [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients) and [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation). However it is impossible to find a solution to every [quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) function. This took many years to figure out.

I would strongly recommend understanding how the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) works for functions. This provides a "numerical solution" instead of a formula which provides a "analytic solution".

There are may [numerical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) techniques that can approximate values that can not be solved directly. Even  quintic equations which sometimes don't have analytic solutions, can be solved with numerical solutions.

Edit:

Here is an example of bisection method.[This quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#A_non-solvable_quintic_example) is not solvable: $f(x) = x^5 - x - 1$. But notice $f(1) = - 1$ and $f(2) = 29$ are opposite signs.

```
bottom <- 1
top <- 2
middle <- (top + bottom) / 2
while top - bottom > 0.0000001 do
   if f(middle) > 0 then
       top <- middle
   else
       bottom <- middle
   end_if
   middle <- (top + bottom) / 2
end_while
```

Running through the algorithm by hand you will notice that `top - bottom` is getting smaller and smaller but `top` and `bottom` are of opposite signs the whole time and surround a root.

Answer (score 2):

"Cardano's method" solves the "reduced" cubic $x^3+ bx= c$ where b and c are real numbers.  The basic idea is:
For any numbers u and v, $(u+ v)^3= u^3+ 3u^2v+ 3uv^2+ v^3$ and $3(u+ v)= 3u+ 3v$ so that $(u+ v)^3- 3uv(u+ v)= u^3+ v^3$.

So, given any two numbers, u and v, taking b= -3uv and $c= u^3- v^3$ we can construct the cubic equation $x^3+ bx= c$ that has solution $x= u+ v$.  Now, what about the other way?  If we know b and c, can we solve $u^3- v^3= c$ and $-3uv= c$ for u and v and so find x?

Yes, of course!  From $-3uv= b$ we have $v= -\frac{b}{3u}$ so that $u^3- v^3= c$ becomes $u^3-\frac{b^3}{3^3u^3}= c$ and, multiplying by $u^3$, $u^6- \left(\frac{b}{3}\right)^3= cu^3$ which we can write as $(u^3)^2- cu^3- \left(\frac{b}{3}\right)^3= 0$, a quadratic equation in $u^3$.

Using the quadratic formula $u= \frac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2+ 4\frac{b^3}{3^3}}}{2}= \frac{c}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{b}{3}\right)^3}$

Then $v= -\frac{b}{3u}$ gives v so we can find x= u+ v.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula.

See the following links

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula

http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html